# Replace text in a file in bash with / in the search string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

How can i replace the following text in a file in linux with a different line

Current :

```
0 22 * * * /scripts/application_folder_backup.sh >> /var/log/application_folder_backup.log
```

Replacement line : #line_removed

I tried using sed but my text in the file already has a / which is causing problems. I tried storing the string in a variable too. But it doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash

var="0 22 * * * /scripts/application_folder_backup.sh >> /var/log/application_folder_backup.log"

sed -i -e 's/$var/#line_removed/g' /tmp/k1.txt
```

exit

Comment: use double quotes for `sed` command. I am not able to find original question to close this as duplicate...

Comment: Only `/` is not a problem, even `*` or all special regex meta characters will be a problem for `sed`

Comment: or use `perl -pe "s|\Q$var|#line_removed|" /tmp/k1.txt` ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest previous to feed the contents of `$var` to the sed script, to escape all the `/` chars to be `\/`, as in:

```
var_esc=$(echo "$var" | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
```

But the `sed` expression gets very complicated (you must use single quotes, if you don't want to double `\` chars, as double quotes do interpret also the backslashes.

Another thing that could simplify the expression is to use the possibility of change the regexp delimiter (with using a different char to begin it) as in:

```
var_esc=$(echo "$var" | sed 's:/:\/:g')
```

The idea is to, before substituting the `$var` variable, to escape all the possible interferring chars you can have (you don't know a priory if there are going to be, as you are using a variable for that purpose) and then substitute them in the final command:

```
sed "s/$var_esc/#line_removed/g"
```

Finally, if you don't want to substitute the line, but just to erase it, you can do something like this:

```
sed "/$var_esc/d"
```

and that will erase all lines that match your `$var_esc` contents.  (this time I believe you cannot change the regexp delimiter, as the `/` introduces the *matching line* operator --- `d` is the command to delete line in the output)

Another way to delete the line in your file is to call `ex` directly and pass the editor command as input:

```
ex file <<EOF          <-- edit "file" with the commands that follow until EOF is found.
/$var_esc              <-- search for first occurrence of $var_esc
d                      <-- delete line
w                      <-- write file
EOF                    <-- eof marker.
```

Comment: Sorry, It should be polite to explain the reasons of a downvote, as not only the question has been answered but also it seems to be the selected answer.  I want also to learn why my answers don't seem to be right for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Just `/` is not a problem here, even `*` or all the special regex meta characters will be a problem for `sed` since it uses only regex for search patterns.

Better to use this `non-regex` based `awk` command:

```
awk -v var="$var" 'index($0, var) { $0 = "#line_removed" } 1' file

#line_removed
```

`index` function in `awk` uses plain text search instead of a regex based search.

Comment: good one, likely OP wants to check against whole line, so `$0==var` is also a choice

Comment: Yes indeed for full line exact match `$0 == var` is the right approach.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. Solved

Comment: @user230994: May I know why you removed acceptance mark and chose an answer that is error prone and can fail for your task.